# How to pass marketing parameters on Redirect in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a controller that resolves "from-anywhere" to a point of origin based on a set of rules:

/from-anywhere/to-anywhere/next-3-months/quality/any-budget?testParam=test

def showFromAnywhere(category: String, duration: String, destination: String, dateRange: String, segment: String, budget: String)

<--action to resolve "from-anywhere"-->

then calls:

Redirect(routes.Frontoffice.showFromOrigin(category, duration, userOrigin, destination, dateRange, segment, budget))

However when the 303 response is sent back it strips out the "testParam=test".

eg. /from-london/to-anywhere/next-3-months/quality/any-budget

These parameters are not used in the controller but in javascript on the client page in order to track marketing parameters (ie. you typical marketing parameters: utm_source=kikolani&utm_medium=320banner&utm_campaign=bpp) .

Is there a way to pass-thru to the redirect these parameters?

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the rawQueryString from the Request object.

If you want to do a Redirect and keep the params (such as for Google Analytics) here is the code

```
Redirect(routes.Application.index() + "?" + request.rawQueryString)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could turn it into a string append what you want to that string and then redirect using that string:

```
def catchall = Action { implicit req =>
  Redirect(routes.Application.index(regular, params).url + "&some=stuff")
}
```